Why is this loop getting error "pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image"
So I am trying to make this so that it will print "hello" until the 'logout' image is found.  But unless the image is immidietly on the screen it will just error out.  I have also tried iterations but that kind of doesnt work because basically I want this to be just constantly checking to see if this image is present every second or so.  I am super new and bad at this so im sure its something easy but I cannot seem to find it.
import pyautogui as pt
import time as t
import random as rand
import cv2

def check_logout():
    logout_image = pt.locateCenterOnScreen('logout.PNG', confidence=.9)
    if logout_image is not None:
        print("Logout image found. Exiting...")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Hello")
        t.sleep(1)

while True:
    check_logout()

I am expecting it to constantly check and once the image is seen then to exit the script.

Could you please share the error as well?

Pyscreese documentation says the following:
 """ImageNotFoundException is an exception class raised when the
    locate functions fail to locate an image. You must set
    pyscreeze.USE_IMAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION to True to enable this feature.
    Otherwise, the locate functions will return None."""

Try to set pyscreeze.USE_IMAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION to False for the expected functionality.
import pyscreeze

pyscreeze.USE_IMAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION = False


Thanks this did work, I am not sure if this is relevant but it still seems to not work when the .py is turned into an exe.  I would think it should still work?

You got the same error?

No the error is gone but the exe just instantly shuts.  Im wondering if thats due to it not wanting to run an infinite loop?

Do not think so, I guess thats a different problem, maybe the way you are creating an exe from this.

hmmm okay ill see if I can figure that out.  Im just using pyinstaller --onefile.  But ill look into it.  Thanks a lot for your help!
